# Fog directory appends local system path with amazon url, when hosting images to s3 with paperclip gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, paperclip, fog

I am trying to host my website that have paperclip attachment images on aws-s3 with fog gem. But my fog directory takes the wrong path but it appends my local file system path with it.

this is my code

```
class RealEstate < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image,
                    :storage => :fog,
                    :fog_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
                    :fog_directory => "#{Rails.root}/config/fog.yml"
end
```

if i define the bucket name here only then it would work but then it would not be able to use different bucket for different env

```
:fog_directory => "development_bucket_name" #works fine but cant use different bucket for different env
```

this is my fog.yml

```
development:
  fog_directory: development_bucket
staging:
  fog_directory: testing_bucket
production:
  fog_directory: production_bucket
```

the path it creates is:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com//home/Desktop//config/fog.yml/real_estate/image/000/000/185/original/4bec7.png?1396429186
```

Comment: Yes Greame i did when i define the bucket name in the model everything works fine. :fog_directory => "development_bucket_name", but then i cant define different buckets for different env.

Comment: what is the fog_directory exactly? Where the images are uploaded to? stored? In the test env... what should it be? Does it need to exist?

Comment: What's the difference between asset_host and fog_directory in the fog_credentials?

Answer (score 1):

Paperclip has no idea that the string you're passing is a path to a config file - it's expecting the actual bucket name.

You need to parse the yaml file and extract the bucket name from it. For example

```
directories = YAML.load(File.read(Rails.root.join('config', 'fog.yml')))
has_attached_file :image,
                  :storage => :fog,
                  :fog_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
                  :fog_directory => directories[Rails.env]['fog_directory']
```